Apache Camel + Spring boot Exception Data format 'jaxb' could not be created
I am new to Apache Camel. My requirement is simple

Program should read the XML
Mask the fields I want
Generate masked XML

I have existing application doing same thing but its not working. Crated new simple spring boot project as below. Requirement to use Apache Camel only.
All below classes in com.example.demo package and sample.xml is present in resources
public class ApacheCamelDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApacheCamelDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=sample.xml&noop=true").unmarshal().jaxb("com.example.demo")
                .bean(new XmlMaskingBean()).marshal().jaxb("com.example.demo").to("mock:output");

    }
}

@Component
public class XmlMaskingBean {

    public void maskSensitiveData(MyXmlObject xmlObject) {
        xmlObject.setCreditCardNumber("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-" + xmlObject.getCreditCardNumber().substring(15));
    }
}

@Component
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
public class MyXmlObject {
    private String name;
    private String creditCardNumber;
}

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-camel-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apache-camel-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I am getting below error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'jaxb' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.dataformat.DataFormatReifier.createDataFormat(DataFormatReifier.java:282) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.dataformat.DataFormatReifier.getDataFormat(DataFormatReifier.java:153) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.dataformat.DataFormatReifier.getDataFormat(DataFormatReifier.java:113) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.UnmarshalReifier.createProcessor(UnmarshalReifier.java:35) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:879) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.addRoutes(ProcessorReifier.java:619) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:224) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    ... 30 common frames omitted


If I add below dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>

Getting below error
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.example.demo" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:241) ~[jaxb-impl-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:58) ~[jaxb-impl-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5 - cb19596]
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:322) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:392) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:349) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.createContext(JaxbDataFormat.java:570) ~[camel-jaxb-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.doStart(JaxbDataFormat.java:534) ~[camel-jaxb-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113) ~[camel-api-4.5.0.jar:4.5.0]
    ... 60 common frames omitted

